# Laurent expansion of $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've come across a problem that, the question is as follows.

Determine the Laurent Series of $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2}$ about $z = 0$.

How would I get started on doing this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the power series for the exponential function:
$$e^u=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {u^n}{n!}$$
With this
$$\frac {e^{z^2}}{z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2n-2}}{n!}=\frac 1 {z^2}+ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{(n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Taylor expansion for $e^x$:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{n!}$$
Then substitute $x=z^2$:
$$e^{z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {z^{2n}}{n!}$$
And divide by $z^2$:
$$\frac {e^{z^2}}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {z^{2n-2}}{n!}$$
Then, it might be desirable to adjust the index with the substitution i=n-1:
$$\frac {e^{z^2}}{z^2} = \sum_{i=-1}^{\infty} \frac {z^{2i}}{(i +1)!}$$